# How to use multiple unique entity in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, echo

public function erase Credentials() using but its not working. Also added 3 field key name in the array parameters in the entity of the model.

Comment: Add some code and any error messages to help people understand what you are asking/working with.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this above the class of the entity. Directly add these 2 annotations to the DocBlock:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="There is already an account with this username.")
@UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="There is already an account with this email.")
```